# How to get previous owner in sql table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Transaction table (transId, sn, customerId, date) that lists item transactions between customers. Some item has sn (serial number) and travels from one customer to another. For some customer (12345678), I need to find out who was the last previous owner of customer's items.

Here's my query:

```
   SELECT c.*, 
          p.transId, 
          p.customerId
     FROM Transaction c 
LEFT JOIN Transaction p ON c.sn = p.sn
    WHERE p.transId = (SELECT MAX(t.transId) 
                         FROM Transaction t 
                        WHERE t.transId < c.transId 
                          AND t.sn = c.sn)
     AND c.customerId = 12345678
ORDER BY p.transId;
```

This query works fine except when item has no previous owner. Should return nulls for p.transId and p.customerId but insead it returns 0 rows. Database is **Access**.

**UPDATE**: I need to have ***BOTH*** current owner and previous owner in result (in one row). And, it should work for middle owners (like a log; if the customer is not current owner, but was a owner before).

**UPDATE**: For certain customer (that would be passed as a parameter; in our case customerId=12345678), I need to see the list of all items that he ever owned and the last previous owner of the items (from which customer he got the item).

Some more explanations:

- transId is a primary key and autonumber (identity) - previous owner will have smaller transId than the newer owner
- customerId in transaction is the buyer (new owner after that transaction)
- date does not contain time; only date (should not be used in comparisons or ordering since some item can change two owners in one day)

Here is a little example that will make things more clearer (date not shown):

```
        transaction table
        -----------------------
        |transId|sn|customerId|
        |      1| 1|  12345678|
        |      2| 2|  87654321|
        |      3| 2|  12345678|
        |      4| 2|  11223344|
        |      5| 2|  12345678|
        -----------------------

        for customerId=12345678 result should be

        result
        --------------------------------------------------
        |transId|sn|customerId|prevTransId|prevCustomerId|
        |      1| 1|  12345678|       NULL|          NULL|
        |      3| 2|  12345678|          2|      87654321|
        |      5| 2|  12345678|          4|      11223344|
        --------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You've either got badly worded homework or you've not relayed the question accurately enough.  Is it "for any item (sn) that customerID 12345678 has ever owned, find me the current owner (customerID) who possesses the item - which may not be customerID 12345678 any more - and any other person who has also owned the piece"?  That would be consistent with 'middle owners'.  Or is it 'find me the current owner (not necessarily customerID 12345678) and the owner who *sold* the piece to customerID 12345678'?  That is a nasty query, and doesn't cover middle owners.

Comment: ...Or...well, there are other possible interpretations.  Another issue: does the transaction table record who sold the item or who bought it (and, indeed, wouldn't it be more normal if recorded both who sold it and who purchased it)?  Also, what is the granularity of the date column - does it record year/month/day or does it include time?  Can a single item be sold multiple times on a single date (probably not if that includes time; possibly if it only includes the year/month/day)?  Are we entitled to assume transID is monotonically increasing with time?

Comment: If what you need is the customerID of anyone who has ever owned an item that customerID 12345678 has ever owned, that is not too hard, even if you want to know the SN of the item that the other customer owned.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thank you for your comments. I have updated the question. I hope it is clearer now.
This is a custom project that I work on so I can change database schema if needed (my schooling days are over, unfortunatelly :( ).
Considering your question whether the seller and the buyer should be included in one row; I thought about it, but that would be redundant information (for instance, if you need to delete some middle transaction, you would have to delete that row and update previous owner of the next row). I will add that only if the problem is not solvable with current schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move condition of `p.transId = ...` from WHERE clause into a JOIN condition (and you do not need `c.sn = p.sn` in any case):

**Normal SQL:**

```
   SELECT c.*, 
          p.transId, 
          p.customerId
     FROM Transaction c 
LEFT JOIN Transaction p 
       ON p.transId = (SELECT MAX(t.transId) 
                         FROM Transaction t 
                        WHERE t.transId < c.transId 
                          AND t.sn = c.sn)
    WHERE c.customerId = 12345678
ORDER BY p.transId;
```

**MS Access SQL:**

```
SELECT      c.*, 
            p.transId, 
            p.customerId
FROM        Transaction c 
LEFT JOIN ((SELECT  t.transId, MAX(z.transId) AS PrevTransId
            FROM    Transaction t 
            LEFT JOIN Transaction z on t.sn = z.sn
            WHERE   z.transId < t.transId 
            GROUP BY t.transId) x
LEFT JOIN   Transaction p ON p.TransId = x.PrevTransId
           ) ON  x.TransId = c.TransId
WHERE       c.customerId = 12345678
ORDER BY    p.transId;
```

Comment: I've tried that (before and now again), but Access reports: "Syntax error in query expression 'p.transId = (SELECT MAX(t.transId)...'.

Comment: @BB: added MS-Access version as well - brrrr, ugly.